# SUMIF cells with a specific column header from multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I have a workbook and macro to calculate sum from multiple worksheets and put it to the master sheet. Below is my current macro which works fine. But I need to add one more additional condition to SUM. I think this can be done by using sumif. I have attached my workbook below explaining about my current outcome and expected outcome.

```
Sub GetSums()
    Dim lngCol As Long, wsName As Range
    With Sheets("Master")
        If .[C3] <> "" Then .Range("C3", .[B3].End(2)) = ""
        For Each wsName In .Range("C2", .[B2].End(2))
            lngCol = Sheets(wsName.Value).Rows(1).Find("My Text").Column
        wsName.Offset(1).Value = _
            Evaluate("Sum('" & wsName.Value & "'!" & Cells(3, lngCol + 1).Address & ":" & _
            Sheets(wsName.Value).Cells(Rows.Count, lngCol + 1).End(3).Address & ")")
        Next wsName
    End With
End Sub
```

### Master Sheet

[image: 1]

### Sheet1

[image: 2]

### Sheet2

[image: 3]

Comment: How do you locate the "department" column? Is it always in the same place?

Comment: Hey Tim. Yes the department column is always B:B I want to add sum if department is "ABC" then sum it up the selected range

Answer (score 0):

This is how it would look using Sumifs:

```
Sub GetSums()
    Dim lngCol As Long, wsName As Range
    With Sheets("Master")
        If .[C3] <> "" Then .Range("C3", .[B3].End(2)) = ""
        For Each wsName In .Range("C2", .[B2].End(2))
            lngCol = Sheets(wsName.Value).Rows(1).Find("My Text").Column
            wsName.Offset(1).Value = _
            Evaluate("Sumifs('" & wsName.Value & "'!" & Cells(3, lngCol + 1).Address & ":" & _
            Sheets(wsName.Value).Cells(Rows.Count, lngCol + 1).End(3).Address & ",'" & _
            wsName.Value & "'!" & Cells(3, 2).Address & ":" & _
            Sheets(wsName.Value).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(3).Address & "," & _
            """ABC"")")
        Next wsName
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

BTW I would normally use End(xlToRight) and End(xlUp) rather than End(2) and End(3) ...